# Как в WordPress создать интерактивную google карту с закрашенными областями?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api

Есть сайт на WordPress. Подскажите, как можно создать на странице интерактивную гугл-карту, на которой кластерами закрашивать области с территорией, где находятся клиенты и возможностью редактирования этого. К примеру: США, Восточная Европа, Индия, Китай, Автралия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раскрашивание стран или других регионов в разные цвета доступно по [Visualization: GeoChart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart).

Вывод на страницу лучше реализовать с помощью шорткода, созданного в своём плагине.

Реализовать настройки можно или параметрами шорткода, или созданием страницы настроек плагина.

Более детально ответить сложно, вопрос достаточно объёмный.

Comment: Круто! Спасибо, впервые увидел такое решение